# Where does the value of CXX in a makefile come from?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Code Snippet:

```
target_test : test.cc 
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) test.cc
```

I know that `CXX` is a variable (containing the compiler command to call), but I was wondering where this variable comes from. The variable is not defined in the makefile and is not an environment variable. Can anyone explain where the value of `CXX` comes from?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Make has several [predefined variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables) among which is `CC`. Initially, it is set at `cc` which is a symlink to the installed C compiler:

```
$ readlink -f `which cc`
/usr/bin/gcc-4.6
```

Also:

```
$ readlink -f `which c++`
/usr/bin/g++-4.6
```

You can change it if you want.

You can use `make -p -f /dev/null` to get a list of all implicit rules and variables. I cannot show the output right now because I have a non-standard install and the output is not in English.

Comment: for example: $ make -p -f /dev/null | grep CXX gives: 
CXX = g++

Answer (score 20):

CXX is an implicit variable in GNU make. [There are others too](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html).

Not only that, these implicit variables get used in [implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules).

Here is an extract relating to how CXX is used by an implicit rule:

> Compiling C++ programs
>       `n.o` is made automatically from `n.cc`, `n.cpp`, or `n.C` with a recipe
>   of the form
>   `$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c`.
>   We encourage you to use the suffix ‘.cc’ for C++ source files instead of ‘.C’.

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone explain where the value of `CXX` comes from?

Like other “magic” variabes (`LD`, `RM`, `MAKE`), it’s predefined internally by make.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variable that an user can override and which has for default value `g++` (in the GNU Make version, at least). There is nothing more to it (it isn't defined in some file or stuff like that).

Source: [The GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables)