# Linux Makefile - CXX is not defined

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does the value of CXX in a makefile come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394659/where-does-the-value-of-cxx-in-a-makefile-come-from)

I'm currently working on a makefile of a legacy project.
The project build successfully with the Makefile.

While inspecting the Makefile, I noticed that it uses `${CXX}` macro to call the compiler.
However, the CXX is not defined in the makefile, and there's no includes of other makefiles.

I tried to see if CXX is an environmental variable, it is not.

Is there a default value for CXX ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html):

```
CXX
    Program for compiling C++ programs; default ‘g++’.
```