# CMake using clang instead of clang++

Tags: c++, cmake, clang

I'm trying to get CMake and Clang to work with my program. I have set the environment variables `CC` and `CXX` as such:

```
export CC=/usr/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
```

But when I run `cmake .` and `make` I get a linker error because it is using `/usr/bin/clang` and not `/usr/bin/clang++` and so cannot see the C++ standard library. After running `make VERBOSE=1`, this is what I get:

```
/usr/bin/clang   -std=c++11 -Wall -O3   CMakeFiles/Saruman.dir/Board.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/Saruman.dir/CaptureList.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Saruman.dir/Evaluation.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/Saruman.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Saruman.dir/MoveList.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/Saruman.dir/Search.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Saruman.dir/TranspositionTables.cpp.o 
CMakeFiles/Saruman.dir/UCI.cpp.o  -o Saruman -rdynamic -lpthread 

CMakeFiles/Saruman.dir/Board.cpp.o: In function Board::Board(std::string)':
/home/terry/code/chess/engine/Source/Board.cpp:(.text+0x100): undefined reference to
`std::string::compare(char const*) const'
```

And it is clearly calling `/usr/bin/clang` instead of `/usr/bin/clang++`. When I manually run

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -O3 ...
```

it compiles perfectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @BaummitAugen No I think it's [just for C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11394799/3299106). Either way, I tried changing CC to `/usr/bin/clang++` and it didn't work.

Comment: This may only be tangentially related, but you may want to try one of the answers to a similar question I asked and see if they work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728685/force-target-link-libraries-to-use-c-linker

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the cpp compiler to cmake directly

`cmake . -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++`

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either. I get exactly the same errors. And it says it's calling `/usr/bin/clang`.